# How to convert a symbolic recursive formula to a non-recursive one

Tags: symbolic, recursion, parametric-functions, sequence

I am new to Mathematica. I want to convert a recursive formula to a non-recursive one using symbolic math. Specifically, I have a recursive formula similar to this:

$a_n = f_a(c_{n-1}, x_{n-1})$

$b_n = f_b(d_{n-1})$

$c_n = f_c(a_n, b_n, y_n)$

$d_n = f_d(b_n)$

with initial values $a_1, b_1$. I want to derive (simplified) formulas $a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n$ that only depend on $x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots , y_n, b_1, a_1$ and parameters of functions $f_a, f_b, f_c, f_d$. All the functions are linear in $x_i$ and $y_i$. For example, the end result for $a_n$ will look like this

$a_n = m_1 x_1 + \dots m_n x_n + l_1 y_1 + \dots l_n y_n$.

I'm looking for simplified formulas for the coefficients (maybe in summation forms). Can I do this using Mathematica? Is so, how? I've seen that [RSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingRecurrenceEquations.html) is used to solve recursive equations but in my case, these equations do not have a simple solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Hi @KRL! Adding a simple code example with (recursive) input formulas and non-recursive output formulas as an edit to your question will very likely increase the chances of getting a helpful answer a lot!